# Creating a multivariate time series with a date column that has many instances of the same date

Tags: r, time-series

This is probably quite simple, but I keep running into walls. I have a data.frame of export data that is laid out like so:

```
year    country_origin    country_destination      value      adjusted_value
1962               ZAF                    PRT    2343000        1.691739e+07
1963               ZAF                    PRT    4131000        2.943756e+07
1964               ZAF                    PRT    4947000        3.479752e+07
1965               ZAF                    PRT    4818000        3.335218e+07
1966               ZAF                    PRT    4534000        3.051438e+07
1967               ZAF                    PRT    5738000        3.746124e+07
1968               ZAF                    PRT    7564000        4.739585e+07
1969               ZAF                    PRT    3619000        2.150258e+07
1970               ZAF                    PRT    4756000        2.672872e+07
1971               ZAF                    PRT    5277000        2.841189e+07
...
```

The first column is the year, second and third are the country pair, fourth is the value in contemporary USD and the fifth is the value inflation adjusted. There are four origin countries and 22 destination countries for 88 total country pairs. My problem comes about when I try to make a time series out of the full data.frame; r doesn't seem to like that I have the years 1962 to 1993 repeating for each country pair and instead treats each observation as a new time, i.e. my second country pair is at t=1994 rather than starting back at t=1962 again.

I've been messing around with zoo a bit to see if that would work better, but I've been unsuccessful. I thought this would be enough, `control1 <- read.zoo(df, format="%Y", FUN=identity, regular=TRUE, index.column="Year", col.names=TRUE, split=Inf)` but it produces the error `Error in FUN(...) : unused argument (format = "%Y")`. I'm not sure resolving this issue alone will resolve my entire problem, but I'm pretty puzzled as to why FUN can't interpret %Y as years. The underlying problem is getting r to interpret my year column as the value of t in a time series. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can also try this community too http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not sure why simply `read.zoo(df)` wouldn't work. You might get a warning, but is this not give the result you want?

Comment: @David_B the simplest answer is usually the best one. I literally never tried using just `read.zoo(df)` in favor of looking at all of the arguments. I think this format will be workable but I'll have to see. Thanks for pointing out what I skipped over.

Comment: If you are not doing a conversion to a Date class then you should not need a format. The zoo pacjkage does not require that its index column be a Date or time class. Integers work just as well.